# Stopping apps updates in android

Tags: android, auto-update

Is it possible to programmatically set OFF/ON  the auto update option in Google Play?

Comment: Not sure this is really off topic, it's a programming question

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. It would only be possible if the Play Store app exposed such a setting via a ContentProvider.